# Loadrunner function to delete a DB data

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I have a Web-application from which I can delete a DB data using  data textfiled, and then clicking on the DELETE button for deleting the data, and it worked fine, and when I check in the DB I found it indeed deleted.
But in Loadrunner script it does not work with this function:

```
web_custom_request("deleteUser", 
                   "URL=https://blabla/deleteUser", 
                   "Method=POST", 
                   "Resource=0", 
                   "Referer=https://blabla.net/", 
                   "Snapshot=t65.inf", 
                   "Mode=HTML", 
                   "EncType=application/json;charset=utf-8", 
                   "Body={\"environment\":\"opint\",\"userIdentifier\":\"{USERID}\"}", 
                   LAST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Record it three or more times and compare the requests being made.  Odds are high that you are missing a dynamic data component in your script and by the time you reach your web_custom_request() your script is off track enough that the business process is not completing as expected.